# How to implement a quartz or cron scheduler in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, ibm-cloud, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

Hi i am having an application which needs to be scheduled in order to perform a task continuously, but i am doing the development on IBM Bluemix cloud and after like 10 days of research i have not been able to find a correct solution to implement a QUARTZ or CRON scheduler in bluemix, in a web application.

whatever i have found out is a service inside the BLuemix called as Workload scheduler but no success has been obtained so far from the steps mentioned there.

Secondly i have found a blog where there are some steps posted to implement scheduler in bluemix, but no success from that as well, the link is mentioned below.

Link: http://sureshgarrepalli.blogspot.in/2015_08_01_archive.html

If anyone here can help me regarding this would be a lot of help. Thanks.

I am using java as my technology and would like to prefer QUARTZ scheduler over CRONJOB.

If someone would be having a snippet of working code, it will be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using OpenWhisk, which has the capability for triggering logic on a scheduled fashion?

See here for details: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_alarms.html#openwhisk_catalog_alarm

Comment: is there any way to use this Open Whisk service using java as technology..?

Comment: yep, that's possible. See here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_actions.html#openwhisk_actions_java

Answer (score 0):

can you add more details on what you want to do? If you want one of your restful services to be invoked, the workload scheduler service will help.
If you want to have a workflow with steps spanning across different systems, monitor the execution of these steps from a user interface, be notified if anything goes wrong etc etc, the workload scheduler service will be your first choice.
Thanks, Umberto

Comment: Consider a scenario where i have a class which runs from main, and i want to schedule it, what to do in this kind of approach. is open whisk a solution.